# List to IEnumerable with parent and child class

Tags: c#

Given the following classes:

```
public class ContentItem : IEquatable<ContentItem>
{
...
}
```

and

```
public class Widget : ContentItem, IWidget
{
...
}
```

why I can't do this:

```
List<Widget> widgets = _repository.GetItems(widgetType);
```

where

`_repository.GetItems(widgetType)` returns `IEnumerable<ContentItem>`?

Essentially I already have a repository implementation which works on `ContentItem` class and I would like to use that same repository also for working with `Widget` class basically because Widget has the same base properties and only introduces few new ones that just hold some information (they come from `IWidget` interface) and don't have any impact on how repository should handle the class). I don't want to make another repository class just to replace all occurences of `ContentItem` with `Widget`.

Should I make my changes by explicitly specifing casts or changing my repository (or repository interface, which I also have)? If possible, I would like to avoid various constructs such as AsEnumerable(), ToList() or explicit casts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a `ContentItem` is not a `Widget` - it's the other way round. Even then an `IEnumerable<ContentItem>` is different from a `List<Widget>`, you can achieve what you want by doing something like this:

```
List<Widget> widgets = _repository.GetItems(widgetType)
                                  .OfType<Widget>()
                                  .ToList();
```

But this will only work **if** you are really returning an enumeration where each `ContentItem` is really a `Widget`.

Comment: Can I do anything on the repository class to support both classes with one same repository?

Comment: @mare: If you want to retrieve `Widget`s you have to create/return `Widget` types within your repository. If the problem is just the casting you could use a generic method in your repository to create/return instances of the right type. It all depends on how you really are constructing instances in your repository - are they really `Widget`s?

Comment: no, they are ContentItems. I had these first, only then the Widget class was introduced.

Comment: @mare: Then you construct cannot work - a `ContentItem` simply is not a `Widget`. You either need a separate repository for `Widget` types or another method that constructs and returns `Widget` instances.